# MySQL SELECT COUNT DISTINCT from 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I previously had 1 column `country` on top of which I performed `COUNT(DISTINCT())` and `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT())`.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(country)) FROM flagevent AS f2
        WHERE f2.user = f.user
    ) AS totalflags,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(country) ORDER BY c.name) AS allcountries,
    f.user, u.username
FROM flagevent AS f
INNER JOIN country AS c ON f.country = c.code
INNER JOIN user AS u ON f.user = u.id
WHERE f.user = 1
    OR f.user in (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY totalflags DESC;
```

That would give me this example result:

```
totalflags | allcountries   | user | username
---------------------------------------------
         5 | es,fr,it,de,pt |    1 | jagomf
```

Now instead of original `country` column, **I have 2 columns** `country1` and `country2` on top of which I have to perform same calculations, getting `DISTINCT` values of both 2 columns.

How can I apply same `COUNT()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` on top of the **distinct data of the 2 columns**?

**UPDATE:** Table schemas:

```
flagevent (old):
- user: int(11)
- country: varchar(2)

flagevent (new):
- user: int(11)
- country1: varchar(2)
- country2: varchar(2)

user:
- username: varchar(45)

country:
- code: varchar(2)
- name: varchar(45)
```

Comment: Provide some data for country1 and country 2 and the table schema.

Comment: Also, please post the entire SQL query you are using.  You are currently asking for a complete answer but giving an incomplete query.

Comment: Updated query and added schemas

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easy way -- just change the new to look like the old:

Note, this was edited to use a CTE since you had the sub query with a count.

```
WITH flagevent_comb as (
   SELECT user, country, COUNT(DISTINCT country) as cnt
   FROM (
     SELECT user, country1 AS country FROM flagevent WHERE country1 IS NOT NULL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT user, country2 AS country FROM flagevent WHERE country2 IS NOT NULL  
   ) x
   GROUP BY user, country
)
SELECT f.cnt as totalflags,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(country) ORDER BY c.name) AS allcountries,
    f.user, u.username
FROM flagevent_comb AS f
INNER JOIN country AS c ON f.country = c.code
INNER JOIN user AS u ON f.user = u.id
WHERE f.user = 1
    OR f.user in (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY user
ORDER BY totalflags DESC;
```

Note you might have to make the sub query more complicated.  For example if sometimes country1 or country2 is null this would probably be better.

```
   SELECT user, country1 AS country FROM flagevent WHERE country1 IS NOT NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT user, country2 AS country FROM flagevent WHERE country2 IS NOT NULL
```

Other business rules might apply.

Comment: Error 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: @Jago -- you put it in the wrong place.  It should be right after the `FROM` to replace the table name you had there.

Comment: I am using your exact code excerpt and I get this error

Comment: @jago -- oops I missed the "count" part -- see above.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately MySQL version used in my server is 5.7 and does not support WITH syntax

Comment: @Jago -- you can make it work the same by replacing everywhere the with query is used with a sub-query.

Comment: Tried but can't seem to get it working; would appreciate some help

Comment: @Jago what more do you expect me to do?

Comment: I don't "expect" anything. Would just appreciate if you -or anyone- could turn that `WITH` expression into a sub-query or anything that server 5.7 can understand, or else I am just not able to confirm this answer.

Comment: @jago -- then you have to work with me -- I described what to do -- did you do that?  did you get an error?  what error did you get?  etc. etc.  Just tossing up your hands and saying it did not work means I will do the same.  Don't treat me like a lap dog -- I'm trying to help you.